# Is there any tool that makes Vim highlight the matches in the file with corresponding xxd output

Tags: vim, binary

Assume that there is a file with its hex representation(`%!xxd`) checked with Vim:
[image]

And is check by `Bless`:[image]
(Note the red box)

In `Bless`, it will highlight the match of the hex in the file, i.e., the character representation of the hex in the file. But in Vim it won't. So I wonder there is any tool to achieve this in Vim? Then I can quickly find the corresponding character.

Comment: what highlight do you expect? cursor location?

Comment: Yes. It will highlight the character representation of the hex value in the file. @mattn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are.

[image]

https://github.com/mattn/vim-xxdcursor

You can enable this with `set filetype=xxd`.

Answer (score 2):

Another (very similar) plugin (by Lech Lorens) can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/A2eBT3nW6rw/q4ny5Zw26VUJ). Apparently, he submitted it to Bram, but it's not yet been included.